# How can mapping of two different values from gridview using c#

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have two GridView names as gv1 and gv2. in gv1, I have a list of database column name and in gv2, I have a list of excel column name.

```
DB Table Columns(gv1)                     Excel Sheet Columns(gv2)
title                                     Title
fName                                     First Name
mName                                     Middle Name
LName                                     Last Name
```

Now i want to map these column. Here 1st value will map with 1st, 2nd with 2nd , 3rd with 3rd and so on. I am using this code to get bind two different gridview:

```
//for database table columns
gv1.datasource = list;
gv1.databind();
//for excel sheet columns
gv2.datasource = list;
gv2.databind();
```

But I don't know, how to get GridView data from 1st to so on.

I am new in C#, please help solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is - map the columns for what purpose?

Comment: I am using this map function in excel upload. So to insert excel data into database, first i map excel column with database table column then its easy to save excel data into db table. Hope now u understand.

Comment: I think you need to say what your actual problem is, not this problem with the solution you have imagined. If I were reading an excel and uploading to a db I'd probably just use oledb provider to load the excel into a DataTable, then have a dictionary that maps the excel column names to the db, I'd rename all the columns in the datatable and upload it to the db

Comment: Tell me, how can i do this. U have any link then please share.

Comment: So you wanna compare DB to Excel or you simply want to import from excel to DB or both?

Comment: Was that comment not already me telling you how I would do this?

Comment: @蕭為元 yes for both. I want to assign excel column to db table column to import excel data.